# Does the new SvgImageSource class designed for UWP can be used in WPF project

Tags: wpf, class, svg, uwp

It seems that a relatively new class: [SvgImageSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.svgimagesource) can only be used in UWP. Is there any way to use it in a WPF project and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be possible to use any UWP XAML UI in WPF [using **XAML Islands**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/xaml-host-controls). This is currently available as a preview using the [`WindowsXamlHost` control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/wpf-winforms/windowsxamlhost) which is part of the **Windows Community Toolkit**. Also note, that when using UWP controls in WPF apps, the app will then work only on Windows 10 client PCs.

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at this framework:
[SharpVectors](https://github.com/ElinamLLC/SharpVectors)

The other way is to convert your SVG files to XAML path geometry and using them easily.